# Get Union values from function annotations?

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing

I'm looking to get the functions' annotations, specifically the Union values of each annotation. Lemme show for an example:

```py
from typing import Union

async def func(arg1: str, arg2: int, arg3: Union[str, int]):
    ...

# Want to get
# {arg3: [str, int], arg1: str, ...}
```

I know `func.__annotations__` returns the dict but I'm not sure about the Union typehints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typing.get_args`:

```
>>> func.__annotations__['arg3']
typing.Union[str, int]
>>> from typing import get_args
>>> get_args(func.__annotations__['arg3'])
(<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)
```